# How to calculate the area between two curves

Tags: matlab, math, area

Based on the following code:

```
clear vars;
close all;

x1 = [0 0 0.01 0.09 0.1 0.11 0.2 0.3 0.35 0.50 0.64 0.8 1]
y1 = [0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 0.30 0.38 0.42 0.45 0.48 0.52 0.86 1]

x2 = [0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 1]
y2 = [0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.9 0.9 1]

plot(x1, y1); hold on;
plot(x2, y2);
```

I need to calculate the area (green area) between the two curves, for example:

[image]

How can I calculate it?

Comment: Running the danger of embarassing myself... Create 2 new functions from the 2 given functions (f1,f2) where ``g1 x = max (f1 x) (f2 x)`` and the other ``g2 x = min (f1 x) (f2 x)``. then Integrate both of them over the range (0..1.0 here) and take the difference.

Comment: And why are there 2 ``0`` values in ``x1`` with different ``y1`` values?

Comment: The data was manually created for the example, it was my mistake. The second `0` can be replaced by another value (e.g. 0.005).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This area is the difference of the two curves integral in the specified domain between each intersection (as mentioned by MBo). Hence, you can find the intersections using [`InterX`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections) and then use `trapz` to do this:

```
P = InterX([x1;y1],[x2;y2]);
area = 0;
% for each segment
% each segment is between P(1,i) and P(1, i+1)
% So we can find xsegments with idx = find(x < P(1,i+1) && x > P(1,i)) and [P(1,i) x(idx) P(1,i+1)]
% ...
    area = area + abs(trapz(xsegment1i,ysegment1i) - trapz(xsegment2i,ysegment2i));
```

Comment: Integrals should be calculated for ranges between intersection points separately, otherwise differences with alternating signs will eat each other.

Comment: No, it does not work (as author expected) in this case. Imagine curves `f(x)=1+Sin(x)` and `g(x)=1` at interval `0..2*Pi`. Your approach gives 0, while "green area" is 4.

Answer (score -3):

Since one of the curves is a straight line you can rotate then add up the areas from the new x axis.

The line is at 45 degrees. So the rotation matrix is

```
 cos 45   sin 45 
 -sin 45  cos 45
```

Multiply each point in the second curve by that matrix. That gives points with the line as the new x axis. Now use area of the triangle (0.5 * width * height) to add up the areas of the fragments.

Comment: Either elaborate quite a bit, preferably with code, or post this instead as a comment. Rotating is by no means a trivial operation in MATLAB. Besides, it's also wrong in this way, as you'll need an absolute value of the then-negative part.